# Não consigo passar parâmetros da view para controller no MVC usando URL

Tags: mvc, controller, view

Estou fazendo um projeto MVC e não estou conseguindo passar para a **Controller** o parâmetro *janelaPesquisa* que está chegando até a **View**. Vou passar as duas classes, se precisar de mais informações vejo de editar aqui:

**ListaGabineteIndex.cshtml**

```
@model Affonso_DW.Models.ListaGabineteModels

@{
    Layout = null;
    int cont = 0;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <label for="Gabinete">
            <b>Gabinetes</b><br />
        </label>

        <div id="accordion">
            <div class="card">

                @foreach (var gabinete in Model.ListaGabinete)
                {
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <!-- comandos data-toggle controlam o layout do menu a ser usado-->
                        <a class="card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-@cont">
                            @gabinete.GabineteDW.Name
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div id="collapse-@cont" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                        <b>Janelas de Pesquisa</b><br />
                        @foreach (var janelaPesquisa in gabinete.ListaJanelaPesquisa)
                        {
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <a href="@Url.Action("JanelaPesquisaIndex", "JanelaPesquisa", new { janelaPesquisa = janelaPesquisa })">
                                    @janelaPesquisa.JanelaPesquisaDW.DisplayName
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                    cont++;
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JanelaPesquisaController.cs**

```
public class JanelaPesquisaController : Controller
    {
        JanelaPesquisa janelaPesquisa = new JanelaPesquisa();

        // GET: JanelaPesquisa
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult JanelaPesquisaIndex(JanelaPesquisa janelaPesquisa)
        {
            JanelaPesquisaModels janelaPesquisaModels = new JanelaPesquisaModels(janelaPesquisa);

            return View(janelaPesquisaModels);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Você não consegue passar valores da "View para Controller", conforme título da pergunta, ou da "Controller para View". O seu `model` na `view` pare ser um array (`Affonso_DW.Models.ListaGabineteModels`) diferente do objeto retornado pela controller (`JanelaPesquisaModels`).

Comment: Estou tentando fazer o URL que está na _ListaGabineteIndex_ passar como parametro o objeto a ser usado na *controller* _JanelaPesquisaController_ para que eu possa assim abrir a nova *view* com as informações desse parâmetro passado. Estava tentando passar um objeto direto para a *controller* e lá dentro eu criava a *model* da qual estaria precisando. Mas o correto é já passar a model correta da *view* para a *controller*, seria isso?

Comment: Veja bem, ao acessar uma URL do seu site, a requisição HTTP passa na `Action` correspondente da `Controller`, aí então você preenche e retorna o objeto da sua `View`. Para passar objeto ao acessar uma URL, declare o parâmetro, na `Action`, e na página que for chamar, crie um `form` contendo `inputs` com os mesmos nomes das propriedades do objeto. Ao submeter o form para a `action`, as propriedades do objeto parâmetro na `Action` serão preenchidos.